# What is the value of an EditText when it is blank with no data?

Tags: android

I want to work with `TextWatcher` to set the value of an `EditText` based on the value of two other `EditText`s :

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    int batie = (superfBatie.getText().toString() == "" ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(superfBatie.getText().toString()));
    int nonBatie = (superfNonBatie.getText().toString() == "" ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(superfNonBatie.getText().toString()));
    int som = batie + nonBatie;
    superfTotale.setText(String.valueOf(som));
}
```

The problem is when the two base `EditText` are not yet populated with data then the app crashed ! So what is the best test condition ? I tried `superfBatie.getText().toString() == null` but same result !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(superfBatie.getText().toString()))
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(superfBatie.getText().toString().length()>0){

                 //your code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can as well check the length of the text :

```
if (superfBatie.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
    //not empty
}
```

Or

```
if (superfBatie.getText().toString().matches("")) {
     //empty
}
```